# Run tomcat in IDEA with before launch command optional

Tags: java, intellij-idea

In my case, when the war is already exist, I just want to start the server. At this time, I have to delete the before launch commond for saving time. And when I want run the before commond I have to add it again.
So is there a way to start tomcat in IDEA with before launch commond optional, and I can choose rather than to add/delete?

[image]

Comment: Can't you just create 2 Run/Debug configurations that do the same thing except one does the before launch command and the other doesn't? Then when you hit `Ctrl+Shift+F9` or `Ctrl+Shift+F10`, you can just pick the one you want.

Comment: It's a way. Thank you.
As I thought there would be a function in IDEA which I didn't find.